# Log4j java.io.FileNotFoundException in web.xml

Tags: log4j, web.xml

My application folder structure

[image]

The Stack trace

java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Eclipse Workspace\Maven_Projects.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Spring_Webapp\classpath\log4j.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)

My web.xml

```
     <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath/log4j.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

but my log4j.xml file is in the class path  but still why I am getting that error message? 
Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classpath/log4j.xml` is a path without any special features (but your brain tricks you into thinking it might be special).

Try `classpath:/log4j.xml` or `classpath:log4j.xml`. Note the colon.